# Difficulty getting spinner working the way I need

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working a few days on this spinner control, though I haven't had very much luck getting it to work the way I need.  It was originally code I found elsewhere, and repurposed for my own needs - so it's just a little bit over my head.

HTML:

```
<ul class="picker">
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">1st Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">2nd Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">3rd Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem win"><span class="value">4th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">5th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">6th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">7th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">8th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">9th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem"><span class="value">10th Item Test</span></li>
    <li class="pickerItem last"><span class="value">11th Item Test</span></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p><a href="#" id="start">start</a></p>
<p>Position: <span id="position">0</span></p>
<p>Speed: <span id="speed">0</span></p>
<p>Deceleration: <span id="deceleration">0</span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var marqueeRunning = false;
var winElement;
var fullSpeed = 60;
var speed = fullSpeed;
var deceleration = 3;
var rotationTotal = 10;
var currentRotation = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

winElement = $(".pickerItem.win");
$(".pickerItem").last().addClass("last");
$(".picker").each(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find(".pickerItem").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css("top", i);
        i += $this.height();
    });
});

$('#start').click(function() {
    if (!marqueeRunning) {
        speed = fullSpeed;
        $("#speed").html(speed);
        //marqueeRunning = true;                
        var countScrolls = $('.picker .pickerItem').length;

        marqueeRunning = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < countScrolls; i++) {
            doScroll($('.picker .pickerItem:nth-child(' + i + ')'));
        }

        setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                marqueeRunning = false;
            }, 
            1000
        );
    }
});
});

function slowDown()
{
var currentTop = Math.floor(winElement.css("top").replace("px",""));
/* -- Bounce Effect
if (currentTop != 0)
{
    newSpeed = speed;
    if (Math.abs(currentTop) < Math.abs(speed *4)) newSpeed = Math.floor(Math.abs(speed) - deceleration);
    if (newSpeed === 0)
    {
        newSpeed = speed;
    }
    if (currentTop > 0)
    {
       speed = Math.floor(Math.abs(newSpeed));
    }
    else
    {
       speed = -Math.floor(Math.abs(newSpeed));
    }
    if (Math.abs(currentTop) < 3 && Math.abs(speed) === 3) speed = currentTop;
}
*/
$("#speed").html(speed);
if (currentTop === 0)
{
    speed = 0;
    $("#speed").html(speed + " (complete)");
}
}

function doScroll($ele) {
//alert($ele.css("top"));
var top = parseInt($ele.css("top"));
//console.log(' Outside - ' + top + ' < -' + 3*fullSpeed);

if (top < -(3 * fullSpeed)) { //bit arbitrary!
//console.log(' Inside - ' + top + ' < -' + 3*fullSpeed);
    var $lastEle = $ele.closest('.picker').find(".last");
    $lastEle.removeClass("last");
    $ele.addClass("last");
    var top = (parseInt($lastEle.css("top")) + $lastEle.height());
    $ele.css("top", top);
}
$ele.animate({
    top: (parseInt(top) - speed)
}, 100, 'linear', function() {
    $("#position").html(winElement.css("top"));
    if ($ele.get(0) === winElement.get(0) && marqueeRunning === false) setTimeout(slowDown, 10);
    if (marqueeRunning || (Math.floor(winElement.css("top").replace("px","")) !== 0 && speed !== 0)) doScroll($(this))
});
 }
```

​
You can view the current version here:  http://jsfiddle.net/STLCajun/FYWtb/

What I'm trying to do is get the spinner to spin, and then after 5-6 rotations, slow down to the list item with the class "win" in the middle.   Can someone point me in the right direction.   Also, I'm not sure why, but it's throwing a gap after the first set of items, and I'm not sure how t get rid of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: should act like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FYWtb/1/): ? many strange code...

Comment: Pretty much - just a little more centered, and after a few rotations.  Definitely in the right direction...

Comment: try [simplescroll](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [simple example](http://jsbin.com/ahexoc/2/) with scrollTo, to make the infinite loop I duplicated number of your items in scrolling window and at finishing scroll to last winning item:

HTML is almost the same as your,

CSS:

```
p {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.pickerItem {
 height:60px;
 width:298px;
 color: #000;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: bold;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.value {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px; 
  padding: 0px;
}

.picker {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 220px;
  width:300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/hMWRu.jpg);
  padding: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
.win span{
 background:blue; 
}
```

JS

```
$.easing.elasout = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t===0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*0.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c;  s=p/4; }
        else s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
    };




$(function() {
  var picker=$('.picker');
  var added_items=picker.children('li').clone(true);
  picker.append(added_items);
  var last=picker.children().last();
  var first=picker.children().first();
  var stop=false;
  var win=$('.picker .win').last();
  var start=function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    stop=false;
  scroll();  
    setTimeout(function() {
     stop=true; 
    },1000);
  };
  var scroll=function()   {
    picker.scrollTo(last,500,{ onAfter: nextstep});
  };
  var nextstep=function() {
    if (stop) {
      picker.scrollTo(first);
      picker.scrollTo(win.prev(),2000,{easing: 'elasout'});
      $('#start').click(start);
      return;
    }
    picker.scrollTo(first);
    scroll();

  };
  $('#start').click(start);


});
```

The biggest problem with initial script is messing with global scope, and do easy things hard.

Comment: Awesome!!   Just curious, is there any way to get it to slow to the correct one, rather than just stopping and "bouncing"?

Comment: I think you can chose/write easing plugin for this,